# Playing a video from session.outputURL with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play a captured video that recorded with AVFoundation and saved in the device's library.
I have the url of the video:

```
NSURL *movieURL = session.outputURL;
```

output:

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F255AC7A-2E0C-40B2-A195-52C03ED5B299/tmp/video.mp4

Now I want to play this video, and I think that the best player for this is the `MPMoviePlayerController` player (let me know if I'm wrong).

This is my code: but for some reason its not working:

```
NSURL *movieURL = session.outputURL;

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview: player.view];

[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
```

It will work then